# Nginx + Gunicorn not showing updated version of Django code

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've uploaded a Django project using Nginx and Gunicorn and domain points correctly. But now when I update/change the code it still shows me the same old message. I've even tried to create an error but still it is showing the old coding based message I used to display for testing. My [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882328/bad-gateway-502-error-with-django-gunicorn-and-nginx/35882669?noredirect=1#comment59467145_35882669) are as provided in link.

Please advise.

Comment: did you restart gunicorn when you made the changes?

Comment: Yes I did using "sudo service nginx restart" and "sudo service gunicorn restart". Both services restarted but still same result.

Comment: What are your settings to run your project? like `python manage.py runserver` or `gunicorn manage.py`?

Comment: gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:9500 -w9 -p /tmp/project.pid --daemon. For complete settings please see the link I've provided.

Comment: What is the name of your upstart script file? and where is it located? The file that has `exec gunicorn ...`.

Comment: for Nginx I've located it /etc/nginx/sites-available/project and its link I've created in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project. For gunicorn I've located the file in /etc/init/project.conf. For settings I've posted a link named "settings" in my original question.

Comment: try `sudo restart project` if that does not work then try `sudo stop project && sudo start project`

Comment: When I used "ps aux | grep gunicorn" it shows sites processes running fine. But when I try to use "sudo restart project" or "sudo service restart project" it says it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: It is much better to use supervisord for this purpose. There is an awesome tutorial about setting up Django with Gunicorn Nginx and Supervisord on virtualenv here (http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105982/discussion-between-shazia-nusrat-and-muhammad-tahir).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am looking for solution right now.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat what is this "same old message" you're getting? You mean an outdated version of your site or something else?

Comment: @YPCrumble the site was not updating when I connect with gunicorn within virtualenv. I simply do " gunicorn myproject2.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:9500 --workers=3 -p /tmp/myproject2.pid --daemon". I think my main issue is that I couldn't get my gunicorn connected to my gunicorn upscript in /etc/init/myproject2.conf file. Somehow I figured it out that the main issue is to activate gunicorn script for virtualenv. If you can help me getting is fixed within gunicorn by keeping at as much simple as possible...it would be a great deal for me.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat, have you found the solution to your problem ?. I am facing the same issue. My gunicorn is not getting updated to the latest code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue in my hello world app on the GCP Compute Engine Instance with nginx, gunicorn, supervisor and systemd configurations.

`It looks like supervisor is not properly restarting the gunicorn`

And I resolved this issue by the following command in my case it worked for me

`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`